# Is any solution in django to compare a foreign key column with primary key inside template, i need specific matchs in my project

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates, foreign-keys, comparison

My View.py
it just render the objects thats fine.

{% ifequal food_ing.f_name food.f_name %}

{{ food_ing.f_name }} --> inside for loop i check this value, and it's (Pizza).

{{ food.f_name }} -- this is also (Pizza) inside for loop in template, but i really don't know why condition equals to False...

My file.html

```
{% for food in foods %}
{% for food_ing in food_ings %}

    **{% ifequal food_ing.f_name food.f_name %} <---> i need this statement to work**
        {% if food_ing.grm_amount == 0 %}
            <tr>
                <th>{{ food_ing.ing_name }}: &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><td class="text-muted font-weight-light">{{ food_ing.ltr_amount }} l</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% if food_ing.ltr_amount == 0 %}
            <tr>
                <th>{{ food_ing.ing_name }}: &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><td class="text-muted font-weight-light">{{ food_ing.grm_amount }} g</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    **{% endifequal %}**
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

My models.py

```
class IngFoodName(models.Model):
    ing_food_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ing_food_name

class Food(models.Model):
    f_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='food_pics', blank=True)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
    f_price = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    f_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    p_duration = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.f_name


class FoodIngredients(models.Model):
    f_name = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ing_name = models.ForeignKey(IngFoodName,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ltr_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    grm_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Food {0} Ingredient {1} Litre Amount {2} Gram Amount {3}".format(self.f_name, self.ing_name, self.ltr_amount, self.grm_amount)
```

Thanks, if anyone know the solution i will appreciate him.

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass `food_ings` from your views? Where does this variable come from?

You can print out all the values inside the for-loop to see what is being compared for debugging

Comment: food_ings is just a variable inside views and it pass FoodIngredients all objects.

Comment: I would just do filtering inside the view and then pass it to the template
food_name = object.f_name
result = Food.objects.filter(f_ing.f_name=food_name)